# Как в winapi убрать кнопки "справка" и "файл"?

Tags: c++, winapi

Даже с стилем WS_POPUP остаются эти мерзкие кнопки и заголовок с названием окна, мне нужно и то и другое убрать(желательно без использования WS_POPUP)

Окно я сейчас создаю так:

```
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, (LPCWSTR)"MyGameComplete",
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ^ WS_THICKFRAME^WS_SYSMENU,
          CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 1280, 720, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
```

вот как окно выглядит сейчас(цветное это мои кнопки)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQPi1.jpg

Comment: Вы же сами пишите  `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`.. Используйте [другие стили](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles). И приложите скриншот как выглядит окно.

Comment: я не нашёл там стиля который без заголовка или кнопок

Comment: Эм... Это как бы меню, а не стиль, и не кнопки. Вы что используете авто-создание проекта? Вот там то меню и выставляется, а если быть точнее смотрите на функцию которая регистрирует класс окна.

Comment: Так нужно убрать `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` потому что это и есть требования заголока.  `WS_SYSMENU` - добавляет меню, и... зачем вы используете исключающее или? Используйте `|` вместо. Я не помню значения констант и не могу предсказать быстро результат `^`. `^` - никто не использует внутри `CreateWindowW`.

Comment: я нашёл в классе окна строку с меню, поставил 0 wcex.lpszMenuName = 0; вроде бы меню убралось, но вот заголовок остался и непонятно где его убирать

Comment: и что вместо WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW поставить?

Comment: Ничего вообще - убрать "слагаемое". Ставте ноль, если соовсем туго. И не используйте исключающиее или - оно запутывает ваш код - используйте обычное.

Comment: если поставлю ноль будет по умолчанию какая-то дичь

Comment: Тогда просто уберите "слагаемое". Какая то дичь это `^`.

Comment: абсолютно то же самое с нулём, по умолчанию видимо ставит этот стиль

Comment: если вы не знаете что значит ^, то собственно это у вас туго, эта вещь убирает часть стиля как оказалось после 1 ссылки в гугле

Comment: И `WS_SYSMENU` тоже убрать. Системное меню - это то, которое в заголовке.

Comment: хелоу ^ MS_SYSMENU значит УБРАТЬ меню

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю что означает `^`, и всётаки считаю что именно его использование пораждает у вас проблему "а почему не работает".

Comment: Да, надо убрать системное меню, потому что оно требует наличие заголовка. Всё верно.  `WS_SYSMENU` тоже убрать, я не ошибся. Пишите стили через `|` потому что да `^` убирает отмеченые биты если они есть, но тогда сложно понять какой у вас результат. Все используют `|` и если вы хотите получить помощь - прийдется делать как все. А потом, когда заработает - тогда можете переделать по-своему.

Comment: я поставил просто NULL и получил все то же окно с заголовком

Comment: Для окон не попап есть такая проблема, похоже прийдется или ставить `WS_POPUP` или обрезать окно через `SetWindowRgn`. Ставьте всместо всего выражения `WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE` и будет то что надо.

Comment: использовал WS_POPUPWINDOW, не знаю почему оно появляется без заголовка в отличие от WS_POPUP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, как я вам уже говорил, это не кнопки у окна, а меню, вы его убрали, теперь что бы убрать рамку у окна, убираем стили у окна после его создания:

```
// Код который создает окно

::DWORD styles = ::GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
styles &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU);
styles = ::SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, styles);

// Здесь уже начинаем обрабатывать оконные сообщения
```

Получаем окно без рамки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Если вы не смотрели на значение макроса `WS_OVERLAPPED` оно равно `0x00000000L`, что аналогично `NULL`.

> `WS_OVERLAPPED == WS_TILED` : Окно является перекрывающимся окном.
>   Перекрывающее окно имеет **строку заголовка и границу**. То же, что и стиль
>   `WS_OVERLAPPED`.